# R package manager to install a hand-made list CRAN packages

Tags: r, package-managers, cran

I'm looking for something similar to `pip install -r requirements.txt` but for R. If I have a list of CRAN packages in a file, is there some package manager that will go ahead and install them? I've looked at a few potential solutions like packrat but they specifically say not to modify the list of requirements by hand which is what I'd like to do

Comment: You could read the file into R, extract the list as a vector, and pass that to `install.packages`. Would that achieve what you're hoping?

Comment: That's currently my backup plan. it seems like a hack. It also gets a bit more complex when I want to specify a specific version of a package.

Comment: Can we have a sample of the file?

Comment: I think the package `pacman` (specifically the function `p_install_version(package, version)`) could be a decent start.

Comment: if you're not going full-on python `requirements.txt` with specific versions or github links, then `install.packages(readLines("requirements.txt"))` ought to work (assuming one pkg name per line)

Comment: `require` gets two birds with one stone, though it doesn't do versioning. I've honestly never found it to matter.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a simple script wrapping [pacman](https://github.com/trinker/pacman) to achieve this.

For example, if you have a file that lists one package per line:

**input.txt**

```
dplyr
ggplot2
etc
```

You could use something like this script to install all the reqs in it:

**installer.R**

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library('pacman')

infile <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)[1]

# check to make sure specified file exists
if (!file.exists(infile)) {
    stop("Invalid filepath specified...")
}

# get list of packages
packages <- readLines(file(infile))
print(sprintf("Installing: %s", paste0(packages, collapse='\n')))

suppressWarnings(p_install(packages, character.only=TRUE))

print("Done!")
```

**Usage**:

`installer.R <packages.txt>`

The nice thing about pacman is that it has the ability to install packages from multiple sources (cran, bioconductor, github, etc.) and can also be used to specify specific package versions. You can imagine then extending this simple script to parse a more complex list including version requirements.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to R. why do I need pacman? install.packages looks like it could do the trick in install.R

Comment: `install.packages` would also work just fine too for simple cases; i just updated the answer to include a note about why you might consider pacman over `install.packges`.

Mainly it has to do with support for software sources and installing specific versions. If everything you want is in CRAN, and you aren't concerned about versions, then you could certainly replace `p_install()` with an `install.packages()` call and drop the dependency on pacman.

Comment: `p_load()` is better here.